# SQL DATEDIFF() and asp.net

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL database to store employee's lunch in, out and total time using SQL DATEDIFF() function. Now if total lunch time is greater than 30mins then displyed result should be in red. I am getting the following error:

> Input string was not in correct format error

SQL table

```
name     |   lunIn                  |     lunOut                  |   lunTot   
A     |  2014-12-23 13:08:53.323   |  2014-12-23 13:39:42.050     |     31
```

ASP.net

```
int lunTotal = Convert.ToInt16(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
if (lunTotal > 30)
{
    e.Row.Cells[4].ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Which line do you get this error?

Comment: int lunTotal = Convert.ToInt16(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);

Comment: Make sure `e.Row.Cells[4].Text` has been filled by using `Int16.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text)`

Comment: Looks like an off-by-one error?  The first column `name` will have index `Cells[0]`, and the last column `lunTot` should be `Cells[3]`. You are looking up `Cells[4]` which is not in your example data set. Consider looking up columns by name instead of by index.

Comment: There is a date column also so column index is correct to 4.

Comment: What is the raw value of e.Row.Cells[4].Text?  Try adding a Debug.WriteLine(e.Row.Cells[4].Text) before that code and see what it prints out.  It should be something that is not parsable into an integer, and will give you a better idea where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I had null or an empty data so it was causing an error.. here is the solution.

```
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int brkDateTotal;
        bool b = int.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[4].Text, out brkDateTotal);
        if (brkDateTotal > 15)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[4].ForeColor = Color.Red;
            e.Row.Cells[4].Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
```